# Sending ADB command from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

I'm trying to save a screenshot using an ADB command with Android Studio, so even if my phone is not connected to my computer, it can still use ADB commands... I can't find any solution on the internet... Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: your phone is not physically connected via USB but connected via Wifi, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WIFI ADB, For that you need to have the Phone and Your Computer on the same network.

To connect using WIFI ADB.

1. Connect your Phone to Computer using USB
2. Open CMD/Terminal/Android Studio>Terminal
3. Type adb tcpip 5555 (make sure you only have your device connected
   and emulators closed) hit enter.
4. Then type `adb <phone-ip>:5555` and hit enter

[Find Phone IP address](https://help.simpletelly.com/article/329-how-to-find-your-android-device-ip-address)

[WIFI ADB App. Check ReadMe. Avoid Installing the IntelliJ Plugin](https://github.com/huazhouwang/WIFIADB)